# When I log transform data, the Lilliefors test still says my data is not normal...why?

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, matlab

I carried out PCA on a dataset, only for someone to point out to me that there is an inherent assumption of normality for this method.

When I checked to see if my data was Gaussian using the `lillietest` function in Matlab, only 2 of my 20 columns returned a zero...meaning that for 18 of them the null hypothesis ("the data are normally distributed") is rejected.i.e. my data are not from a normal distribution.

Then I thought I could simply log transform the data (x) to give me a normal distribution. However, when I do this using:

```
for i=1:20;
xnorm(:,i)=log(x(:,i));
l(i)=lillietest(xnorm(:,i));
end
```

I am still getting mostly 'ones' returned from the `lillietest` function. Should each column not be normal following the log transform?

I also tried using the boxcox transform, however, despite all my data being positive, I keep receiving this error:

```
    Error using boxcox (line 51)
    Input DATA must be positive.
```

Is there a way I can transform my data to a normal distribution, so I can adhere to the assumption of normality required for PCA?

Comment: I don't think PCA "assumes" multivariate normality at all. Here, as usually, **assumption** is better read as **ideal condition**. Generally, PCA is a transformation method; it is often true that highly skewed data will be awkward and PCA may not be especially helpful for such data, but that's empirical, not a matter or principle. Specifically, some inferential machinery that people have built on PCA is based on multivariate normality, but these are add-ons, not the main method.

Comment: Correct spelling is Lilliefors. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Some seem to say that normality is required, while others say it isn't..this is true. I suppose I haven't read any articles that have convinced me that it is ok to ahead with PCA without transforming the data somehow. Thanks for the spelling correction.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no one transformation of data from an unknown distribution which will always redistribute into a normally distributed variable. Log-transformation might help for variables with considerable right skew, but would not work (i.e. 'normalize') on continuous variables with negative values (e.g. differences) or those with left skew or other non-normal distribution.

Additionally, assuming log-transformation is applicable, you might wonder if your test for normality isn't driven by your sample size (which you have not described, so could be relatively large), and the test has given you a rejection of the null-hypothesis which is based on only a small deviation of normality.

Finally, I'm really curious why you'd want normally distributed variables for your entire dataset. I can understand transforming specific variables based on the desired modelling assumptions (such as transforming of a specific variable with an obvious non-linear association with another variable studied). But normalizing (so not standardizing or mean-centring) everything might not be what you need. 
Also, PCA assumes ***multivariate*** normality, which is explained quite well [here](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-implicit-Gaussian-assumptions-in-the-use-of-PCA-principal-components-analysis). So normalising for that reason is not really necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would work on all variables whether they were right or left skewed. My sample size is 20 x 200 (20 variables and 200 objects). What you say is very valid...my sample size is not very big, so if it was, the data could approximate a normal distribution.

Comment: does the assumption of multivariate normality not mean that every variable (column) in my dataset has to have a normal distribution? Which is what I was doing in the loop...individually transforming each column?

Comment: You can drop the 'AFAIK'. How could there be?